# TypeError: must be string, not date for strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to implement the following : a function to return the third-latest date, given such an array of Date objects

This is the solution I came up with, and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must be string, not date
```

---

```
import datetime
def third_latest():
    timestamps = ['2011-06-2', '2011-08-05', '2011-02-04', '2010-1-14', '2010-12-13', '2010-1-12', '2010-2-11', '2010-2-07', '2010-12-02', '2011-11-30', '2010-11-26', '2010-11-23', '2010-11-22', '2010-11-16']
    dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in timestamps]
    dates.sort()
    sorteddates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in dates]
    return str(sorteddates[3])

def main():
    third_latest()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I run your code (in either Python 2 or Python 3) I get the output `'2010-02-11'` with no error.

Comment: You will need to reformat the dates in `timestamps` to be consistent, so that they sort properly. I notice that one of the dates has a one-digit month whilst others have two-digit months.

Comment: %m-%d-%Y should take care of that automatically

Comment: One issue -- you call your function `third_latest()` but are using the *fourth* index (3 is 4th in 0,1,2,3)

Comment: You're right, of course. I can't reproduce the error. Can you give us the trace produced in stderr? That would indicate precisely where exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

**strftime** converts **datetime** objects into strings according to formats.

Replace :

```
sorteddates = [datetime.datetime.strftime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d") for ts in dates]
```

with

```
sorteddates = [ts.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for ts in dates]
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for **strftime**.

Also, you can check out the [working version of your code here](http://ideone.com/OSvC0H).

Comment: This happens ONLY for strptime, and I can't figure out why!

Comment: Its working fine for me. Can you add the complete traceback ?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Check the working version of your code on the link i added in the answer.

Comment: That seems to be working, I agree and I cna't figure out why my code isn't working

Comment: Try copy pasting the code from the url in a new file and see what happens ?